# Android notification sound doesn't work

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android

```
var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Application.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon))
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(message)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)                 
                .SetStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().BigText(message))
                .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))
                .SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 })
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All);

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Where i was wrong? Why my notifications doesn't have any sound or vibration?

Comment: do you have the appropriate permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @th3pat3l, i am just added this. android.permission.VIBRATE

Comment: try changing the vibrate to this: `SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });`. From what i understand, its suppose to be `{ delay, vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep }` pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All)`, you are **resetting** the notification settings that you just built:

```
var notification = new Notification.Builder(Application.Context)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.Icon)
    .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Application.Context.Resources, Resource.Mipmap.Icon))
    .SetContentTitle("Stack")
    .SetContentText("OverFlow")
    .SetAutoCancel(true)
    //.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .SetStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().BigText("OverFlow"))
    .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))
    .SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 })
    .Build();

var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried with setting up set sound and set vibrate but I doesn't get sound when push notifications are received. Please suggest what I am missing.

Comment: @Deepak Without seeing how you are building the notifcation in the BroadcastReceiver I would have no idea what is wrong, you should post a new question with the code that is not working.

Comment: Okay Sushi. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing uri to setSound in notificationBuilder like this

`Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
 notificationBuilder.setSound(uri);`

Comment: if you can see the notification then try setSound and setVibrate one by one and see if anything happens. I think setVibrate() is causing some trouble because I've used this uri method in my projects and its working.

Comment: Hmm. Works now, but how to set vibration?

Comment: With help from https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html and another answer here this can help you notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });